# How to write Ember helper to compare new ember model records with id=null

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

Hello I have selectbox filled with options from model, where i set initially selected item by comparing records ids with id of currently selected item in relation model :

```
selected=(eq task.reaction.id reaction.id)
```

Everything works just fine, till I create new reaction records on frontend which have "null" value in "id" .

when I try to compare straight objects (i do not want to compare them just to find if they point to same ember model object/record)

```
selected=(eq task.reaction reaction)
```

It does not work, I tried to write custom helper, but i have trouble with
comparing those ember objects, since they are somehow different even while they have same id (screen from chrome debugger objects info https://i.stack.imgur.com/QT1Xp.jpg)

Comment: You should probably not use model ids for this. I'd just create an array of options and use the indeces of the local array.

Answer (score 0):

After a while I found out that in case of model that is taken from belongsTo, its object has its record stored in "content" property, with this in mind I could finnaly write helper I needed.

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export function eqRecord(params/*, hash*/) {
    let firstObject = params[0];
    let secondObject = params[1];
    let firstRealRecordObject;
    let secondRealRecordObject;

    if(!Ember.isEmpty(firstObject.content)){
        firstRealRecordObject = firstObject.content;
    } else {
        firstRealRecordObject = firstObject
    }

    if(!Ember.isEmpty(secondObject.content)){
        secondRealRecordObject = secondObject.content;
    } else {
        secondRealRecordObject = secondObject
    }


    return firstRealRecordObject === secondRealRecordObject;
}

export default Ember.Helper.helper(eqRecord);
```